# Extract a column from whitespace-separated fields that are not aligned

Tags: text-processing, columns

How can we extract a column from output in which whitespace is not in a regular format?

For example, when we type `ps -ef`, it shows all the process, process id's.... etc. How can we get only the last column or any specific column?

Comment: Even if we go for ls -l in any directory the number of white spaces between the columns would be uneven.

Answer (score 3):

Using `-o` option you can specify what fields should be displayed. List of available fields you can find in `man ps` or using `ps L`.

For example using `ps -eo user,command` will display usernames and commands - something like this:

```
root /bin/login --
root /sbin/getty
```

You can also use `-O` and parameters which will cause using some default fields and appending that specified by you, but if you want to parse output I will recommend `o`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want:

```
ps -eo comm
```

To get the command name or

```
ps -eo args
```

To get the command args or

```
ps -eo args="Last-Arg" | awk '{print $NF}'
```

To get the last argument.